# Make batch file closes only IF a program is running longer than a certain duration

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imacros

I have made a batch file that restarts a script the moment it closes. The script either runs for 2 mins or 15 mins. I want to make the batch file self close if the script didn't close after 2 mins which means that it has successfully worked and the batch file is no longer needed. In other words:

1. Batch file runs script
2. Batch file waits for the script to close before 2 mins
3. Restarts the script after 60 seconds
4. If the script runs longer than 2 mins, the batch file exits and the script 
   never restarts again.

My question is: how do i edit the code to make the batch file closes IF the script has been running for more than 2 mins?

Note: I am talking about iMacros scripts here. They automatically self close if failed/finished so no need to kill the process. File extension: .iim

Here is my current code:

```
 @echo off
:start
set /a var+=1
if %var% EQU 10000 goto end
:: 
TIMEOUT /T 60
cd C:\filepath
program.iim
goto start

:end
echo var has reached %var%.
pause
exit
```

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: I edited the post to include needed information. Sorry, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: How do you know that the "script" (program.iim) has stopped? Is a file written or deleted? Do you need to keep track of the process?

Comment: The batch file automatically pauses running when it launches the script and waits for it to close then loops back to 60 seconds countdown to another launch

Comment: @Shardinar - After the script starts, `program.iim`, there is a `goto start`. In what way does the batch file wait for `program.iim` to close?

Comment: I think it's similar to the "START /wait file.exe" command. The batch file stays on hold until the process "file.exe" is dead.

Comment: Are you saying that running `program.iim` will finish and exit before the `goto start` is processed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go through the rest of your script, so will only show what you asked for, that is if I understood the question correctly. You basically want to check if `program.iim` is still running, you want to exit the batch script. If so, then this might help:

```
title myscript
timeout /t 120 >nul
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq program.iim" |findstr program.iim
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myscript"
```

So what happens is, we set the title of the batch file to `myscript` then do the timeout of 2 minutes check if the task `program.iim` is running (that is if this actually creates a image by this name) and by using `findstr` if the image is still running, we simply kill the batch file by it's titlename.

you could then maybe add another line:

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto :start
```

Which will let you restart `program.iim` should it not be running by the time you check for it. Note, `title myscript` should preferably be at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but it looks like it might do what you are seeking. I do not have iMacros. I apologize if it does not work.

The iMacros.exe program is run once before the while loop begins because my guess is that you do not want to wait 60 seconds for the first start. Put this code in a file named `timesp.ps1` (or another name ending with .ps1).

```
$starttime = Get-Date
Start-Process -FilePath iMacros.exe -ArgumentList "program.iim" -Wait

while ((New-TimeSpan -Start $starttime).TotalMinutes < 2) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    $starttime = Get-Date
    Start-Process -FilePath iMacros.exe -ArgumentList "program.iim" -Wait
}
```

Run this script using:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File timesp.ps1
```